# Is it possible to push annots to selectedAnnots in Adobe Acrobat Pro using javascript?

Tags: javascript, adobe, acrobat

I know that it is possible to read this.selectedAnnots property if user has some annots selected, however I am curious whether it is possible to programmatically select annot and add it to the this.selectedAnnots collection?

Answer (score 0):

The selectedAnnots property is read-only. It is not possible to programmatically select an annot.